# Run processing only in layers with selection

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, select

First of all, I am really begginer with PyQGis...

I am trying to run a random point algorithm in different vector layers of a folder. But I dont want to do it for every polygon, only for selected ones. The selection is done with a geometric filter and with an attribute filter.

When I run the code it is working perfectly for the layers in which the filters selects different polygons, but in those in which the selection gives no answer (because they are out of the geographical filter) the algorithm runs on every polygon... and I need exactly the oposite, not to run in any polygon.

I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work... Here is the code:

```
import os
import processing

#Selection of layers
path="/home/basi/Escritorio/GEA Forestal/SATree/MFE/Todos/Seleccion/"
capas = os.listdir(path)
for capa in capas:
    if os.path.splitext(capa)[1]==".shp":
        layer=iface.addVectorLayer(path+capa,"_","ogr")
#Filters
        Area=QgsRectangle(-4,39,-4.2,44)
        exp = QgsExpression('FORM_ARB_D ILIKE \'%pino albar%\'')
        request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
        request.setFilterRect(Area)
        features = layer.getFeatures(request)
#Selection
        ids = [i.id() for i in features]
        layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
#Random point algorithm
        Output_layer="/home/basi/Escritorio/GEA Forestal/SATree/Eleccion poligonos prueba Solo Sentinel/Programacion seleccion/parcelas_longitud_PS_"+os.path.splitext(capa)[0]+".shp"
        processing.runalg('qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed',layer,0,3,0.0006,Output_layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Introduce an *if* statement**.

If there are selected features, run the algorithm otherwise do nothing:

```
#Random point algorithm
if ids:
    processing.runalg('qgis:randompointsinsidepolygonsfixed',layer,0,3,0.0006,Output_layer)
```